# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML

Tags: java, android

I get this exception "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML" in API under 24. Problem is in ImageButon, here is code

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/buttonSettingImage"
    android:onClick="butSettingsClick"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/butPlay"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/geer" />
```

and this is how I store the image [image: file hierarchy]

I think the problem is caused by image 'geer.png'

Comment: Sometimes, the android studio plays with us. Just clean the project from Build option and Rebuild it.  It might be work for you,

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one image (not resized for each resolution), then right click on the image, go to **Reveal in Finder/Folder** and put the image inside the **src/main/res/drawable** folder.

Depending on what your minimum supported SDK version is, you can try out using `android:src="@drawable/geer` instead of `app:srcCompat="@drawable/geer"`

You can also try out this tool to resize your image to fit all resolutions: [App Icon Generator](https://appicon.co/#image-sets) and put the images in the respective `drawable` folders.

Comment: I triad 2nd option and it didn't work. My min supported API is 21 but it crashes under 24. I use many images in my app but all are loaded from the assets folder and it works. So I just move "geer.png" to the assets folder. One minus is that I have to load an image in code when the app starts and use AssetsManager

Comment: Post the stack track you see in the Logcat, it usually gives a better idea of where the issue would be. And any specific requirement why you use place your images in assets instead of drawables? And if you replace your `geer.png` with another image in the drawable folder, does that work or still crashes?

Comment: I use in my app many images and they have to be in specific folder hierarchy (sth like this https://ibb.co/CvJnKDv, in folder "Cards", are images). Can I add subfolders in "drawable" folder? I haven't tried to replace geer.png with another image. Btw is this bad to keep images in assets folder?

Comment: In most cases, the images are placed in the `drawable` folders, and are sub-divided into `drawable-mdpi` `drawable-hdpi` `drawable-x+xx+xxxhdpi` to work across multiple resolutions. If you don't have images for each resolution separately, you usually place them inside the `drawable` folder. No, we cannot add subfolders in the `drawable` folder. The `assets` folder is not normally used for app images. Its purpose is to accommodate other assets, could be anything, like 3D models, html web pages, sound files, text files, etc. Items in drawable folders can be accessed in the app more efficiently.

Comment: So if I can't add subfolders into the drawable folder I have to use assets because whole logic in my app based on folders hierarchy and images name :/ but thanks for everything :D

Comment: Fair enough. Noe issues mate.

Answer (score 0):

Put your image from `src/main/res/drawable-v24` to `src/main/res/drawable`